# Risers or bars of Dynamically built ChartJs from json not aligning to bottom of y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynamic, chart.js

I have strange behaviour from bars or risers in a dynamically built Chartjs chart.
They don't begin at point 0 on the y-axis and not all of them show.

I have tried a variety of ways as found here or other forums, but no success.
Please help.
[image]

The code to build it is from json ex ajax to MVC Controller/Action.

```
chartSetup.jsonDataSets = new List<ChartDataset>();

        ChartDataset jsonDataSets = new ChartDataset
        {
            data = "[408, 547, 675, 534]",
            label = "Actual",
            backgroundColor = "#8e5ea2"
        };
        chartSetup.jsonDataSets.Add(jsonDataSets);

        jsonDataSets = new ChartDataset
        {
            data= "[350, 447, 725, 534]",
            label = "Budgeted",
            backgroundColor = "red"
        };
        chartSetup.jsonDataSets.Add(jsonDataSets);
```

If I hardcode particularly the datasets, for the chart, then no problem.

[image]

```
var type = 'bar';
var xLabels = ["May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept"];
var topTitle = { display: true, text: 'Maintenance Costs', fontStyle: 'bold', fontSize: 18, fontColor: 'white' };

var canvasTyreCostsChart = $("#canvasMaintenanceBar").get(0).getContext("2d");

var datasources = [
        {
            label: "Budgeted",
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            data: [133, 221, 783, 1078]
        },
        {
            label: "Actual",
            backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
            data: [408, 547, 675, 734] 
        }
    ];

    var regionalCountCostBar = new Chart(canvasTyreCostsChart,
        {
            type: type,
            data: {
                labels: xLabels,
                datasets: datasources,
            },
            options:
            {
                responsive: true,
                title: topTitle,
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            }
        });
```

But done dynamically the bars float above the zero point on the y axis.
Here's the code.

```
datasources = jsonData['jsonDataSets'];
var dynamicChartCanvas = $("#canvas-" + columnID).get(0).getContext("2d");
    var xLabelsArr = []; 

    $.each(xLabels, function (key, val)
    {
        var rec = xLabels[key];
        xLabelsArr.push(rec['label']);
    });

    var label;
    var backgroundColor;
    var data2 = "";
    var data3 = [];
    var DS = [];
    var dataSource2;

    // Extract the individual elements
    $.each(datasources, function (key, val)
    {
        var rec = datasources[key];

        $.each(rec, function (key, val)
        {
            if (key == "label")
            {
                label = val;
            }
            if (key == "backgroundColor")
            {
                backgroundColor = val;
            }
            if (key == "data")
            {
                data2 = rec[key];

                var xx = data2.replace("[", "").replace("]","").split(",");
                data3.push(xx);
            }
        });

        dataSource2 =
        {
            label: label,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            data: data3,
        }

        console.log("ds label " + JSON.stringify(label));
        console.log("data3 " + JSON.stringify(data3));

        data3 = [];
        DS.push(dataSource2);       
        
    });

    console.log("DS " + JSON.stringify(DS));

    var tempData2 = {
        labels: xLabelsArr,
        datasets: DS,
    };

    var topTitle = { display: true, text: 'Maintenance Costs', fontStyle: 'bold', fontSize: 18, fontColor: 'white' };

    var chart = new Chart(dynamicChartCanvas,
    {
        type: type,
        data: tempData2,
        options:
        {
            responsive: responsive,
            title: topTitle,
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
        }
    });
```

The object array as logged:

```
DS [{"label":"Actual","backgroundColor":"#8e5ea2","data":[["408"," 547"," 675"," 534"]]},{"label":"Budgeted","backgroundColor":"red","data":[["350"," 447"," 725"," 534"]]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What was required, was a further iteration thru the JSON array in the data object, getting each value and building it into a js array.

```
            if (key == "data")
            {
                var dataRec = rec[key];
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(dataRec);
                xValuesArray = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
                {
                    var value = jsonData[i];
                    xValuesArray.push(value);
                }
            }
        });

        chartDataset =
        {
            label: label,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            data: xValuesArray,
        }

        chartDatasets.push(chartDataset);
```